# Azure AD - Expose an API to consume it with application permissions

Tags: api, azure-active-directory

I'm developing a custom API and a windows service. I want to use Azure AD for authentication and authorization between the api and the windows service.

My question ist: How can I expose the API, so that I can add the api permissions to the win service with the type "application permissions"?

I can only select "delegated permissions" when I want to add the api permissions to the win service. But I need "application persmissions" because the win service runs without an user.

Thank you in forward!

Best regards
Matthias

---

Ok. Now I know how to set up the manifest in the app registration. I also get a bearor token and in the bearor token I can see (if I bas64-decode it) the Client ID of the Web API and also the App roles: "roles":["User.Sync2"]
So I think that the token is correct.

In the second step I call the Web API (https://localhost:44358/api/AzureADB2C/Ping) with authentication "Bearor" and the token. But then I receive a 401. (I have not registered any platform in the app registration for the Web API and therefore also no redirect URI. But I think I don't need it?)

Here's the Startup.cs of my Web API project (It's standard generated with Visual Studio):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AzureADB2CConnect.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my API Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AzureADB2CConnect.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AzureADB2CController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Ping")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "User.Sync2")]
        //[Authorize]
        public async void GetPing()
        {
            //foreach(Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
            //{

            //}
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the "Authorized"-Tags I can call the API. And it doesn't matter If I use only Authorize or Authorize(Roles = "User.Sync2") I always receive a 401.

Where is the error/bug?

Thank you in forward!

---

Here is the decoded bearor token:
[image]

---

That's how I call the GET-Method to get the token:
[image]

Comment: My article might help here: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your token and provide screenshots.

Comment: Are you exposing the api of the Azure AD application or the api of the Azure AD b2c application?

Comment: For this api I'm using Azure AD not Azure AD B2C. And I've added a screenshot of the decoded token.

Comment: The reason for the 401 is that you used the wrong token to call the Api. Check the `aud` of your token to make sure it is consistent with the Api you want to request.

Comment: What's wrong with the aud? What is the right value for aud? I've added a screenshot from Postman how I call the bearor token...

Comment: @MatthiasWirth   Try to change `Authorized` to `Authorization`, and change `Bearor` to `Bearer`, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add app roles. Please follow [How to: Add app roles in your application and receive them in the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps). App role *allowedMemberTypes* should include *Application*.

Comment: Thank you Alfredo R. and juunas. I think that's what I was looking for. Now I've implemented an app role in the manifest of the app registration in Azure AD.

But now I don't know how to call the Web API in my windows service (not hosted in Azure). I already called successfully the Microsoft Graph API with a bearor token. But I don't know how to change this code to use it for my Web API. I already receive a bearor token. But when I want to use this token for my Web API I get a 401. I don't know if the error is in my win service or in the Web API.

Comment: Hi Alfredo. I tried this but no luck. I asked a question here. Can you please take a look and help out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69292198/how-do-i-expose-an-azure-ad-application-api-and-give-it-application-permissions

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem. You entered the wrong parameters when verifying the token. You need to change `Authorized` to `Authorization` and `Bearor` to `Bearer`.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for answering late but I was very busy with another project. I've already used "Authorization" and "Bearer". This where only misspellings here in the posts. But in Postman it's written correct. Now I've contact a business partner for development support. I will tell you se answer when I know it. But if you have another idea I will be very grateful!